# Target an parent element but without knowing how many nodes are in between child and parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

The HTML may be:

```
<div class="SomeWrapper">
    <img scr="img2.jpg" />
    <img scr="img3.jpg" />
    <img scr="img4.jpg" />
    <img scr="img5.jpg" />
</div>
```

or it could be

```
<div class="SomeWrapper">
    <li><a href="#"><img scr="img1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img scr="img2.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img scr="img3.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img scr="img4.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img scr="img5.jpg" /></a></li>
</div>
```

my javascript is checking for a loaded image. On image loaded, it wants to apply some effects to the first parent element after "SomeWrapper" div (not the image itself).

Normally I would do something like `.parent().parent()` but I don't always know how many parents the image will have.

```
$obj.find("img").load(function(){
    $(this).parent().animate({opacity: '1'},{duration: settings.fadeSpeed});
});
```

How could I target the correct parent in place of `$(this).parent()` above?

**edit**:
`$obj` happens to be the element I want to target

**edit 1**: 
I don't know the value of parent class name, in this case ".SomeWrapper" so I can't use $(".SomeWrapper")

I could get that value by fetching it from the DOM though, but I would prefer a relative solution that doesn't rely on hardcoded classes or id's

**edit 2**:
Here are the actual files

https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/f4fb3f12750394acdd627fc4d2f2aa3a5091e17d/examples/example-size-in-tag.html

Here I want to replace `.parent().parent()` as it's a dynamic value https://github.com/ed-lea/jquery-collagePlus/blob/f4fb3f12750394acdd627fc4d2f2aa3a5091e17d/jquery.collagePlus.js#L316

Comment: Is the parent an immediate child of 'body' or some other div that you are sure of?

Comment: the parent I want to target will always be the first child of ```<div class="SomeWrapper">```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has also .parents( [selector ] ) method

According to the documentation:

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the
>   latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

So in your case you can use:

```
$(this).parents(".SomeWrapper").animate({opacity: '1'},{duration: settings.fadeSpeed});
```

UPD:
Accodring to changed question:

> edit: $obj happens to be the element I want to target

What about:

```
$obj.find("img").load(function(){
    $obj.animate({opacity: '1'},{duration: settings.fadeSpeed});
});
```

If you have loop you can use closure:

```
$obj.find("img").load(function(target) {
     return function(){
         target.animate({opacity: '1'},{duration: settings.fadeSpeed});
     }
}($obj));
```

Comment: This will select ALL parents item with SomeWrapper class.
You better use closest or $(this).parents(".SomeWrapper").first()

Comment: Also, I don't want to target .SomeWrapper, I want to target the first level of child that contains the image I was loading.

Comment: If you have $obj defined and $obj is your target, so what about using it directly in your handler function?

Comment: @Artem yes, exactly what I thought, but when I tried it, it didn't target correctly. It seems that in the .each() loop I'm in, it would override the $obj so miss all but the last one.

Comment: @ed209 So you can use closure for that case. I udated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to do that

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest('.SomeWrapper').parent().animate({opacity: '1'},{duration: settings.fadeSpeed});
```

Comment: thanks, not quite what I need. I updated my question to try to explain better. I basically want to target the first child of ".SomeWrapper" that contains the image I was loading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `closest()` to get the `.SomeWrapper` element then `parent()` to go up 1 further level in the DOM. Try this:

```
$obj.find("img").load(function(){
    $(this).closest('.SomeWrapper').parent().animate({ opacity: '1' },{ duration: settings.fadeSpeed });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that none of the children of 'somewrapper' have the same class name, you can use the .closest() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
$(this).parents('SomeWrapper')
```